# Update WPF TreeView tree node Image after a tree node property has changed

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I am an FPGA engineer working on a GUI development and totally new to WPF and XAML, so please forgivemy poor technical lexicon.
I want to show a tree of networks and their node members. I based my TreeView on the guidelines given in [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/), based on data binding, and  multiple  HierarchicalDataTemplate.
I want that the image of each node depends on a the value of a property of the node, called IconColour, that will inform the user if that node is connected (green circle) or disconnected (red circle), and few more, but this gives the idea. During the program execution, the node can switch its status between connected and disconnected.
I managed to bind the node image to the value of the property `public Icon_colour Icon;`, using `<Image Source="{Binding DisplayedImagePath}" Height="12" Width="12" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>`, where DisplayedImagePath  returns a string with the name of the image file, depending on the value of the variable `Icon`.
This is the relevant XAML TreeView code

```
<TreeView Name="trvNetworks" Background="Transparent">
                        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                            </Style>
                        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <TreeView.Resources>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type self:NetworkList}" ItemsSource="{Binding Networks}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu>
                                                <MenuItem Header="New Network" Click="NewNetwork_Click"></MenuItem>
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:Network}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Add Nodes" Click="AddNodes_Click"></MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Delete Network" Click="DeleteNetwork_Click"></MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Config Network" Click="ConfigNetwork_Click"></MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Query Network" Click="QueryNetwork_Click"></MenuItem>
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nodes.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:Node}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding DisplayedImagePath}" Height="12" Width="12" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Delete Node" Click="DeleteNode_Click"></MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Config Node" Click="ConfigNode_Click"></MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Query Node" Click="QueryNode_Click"></MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Display Info" Click="DisplayInfo_Click"></MenuItem>
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TreeView.Resources>
                    </TreeView>
```

This is the node class

```
 public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone_number { get; set; }
    public string Network_name { get; set; }
    public string File_name { get; set; }

    public enum Icon_colour
    {
        green,
        yellow,
        red,
        black
    };

    public Icon_colour Icon;

    public string DisplayedImagePath
    {
        get
        {
            switch (Icon)
            {
                case Icon_colour.green:
                    return @"D:/projects/010_ECR/ecr_gui/EcrGui/bin/Debug/images/circle_green.png";  
                case Icon_colour.yellow:
                    return @"D:/projects/010_ECR/ecr_gui/EcrGui/bin/Debug/images/circle_yellow.png";
                case Icon_colour.red:
                    return @"D:/projects/010_ECR/ecr_gui/EcrGui/bin/Debug/images/circle_red.png";
                case Icon_colour.black:
                    return @"D:/projects/010_ECR/ecr_gui/EcrGui/bin/Debug/images/circle_black.png";
                default:
                    return @"D:/projects/010_ECR/ecr_gui/EcrGui/bin/Debug/images/circle_black.png";
            }
        }


    }

}
```

When I initialize each node, I can see that the image is correctly displayed according to the value given to `Icon`. Then, I change the value of the property at the event `ConfigNode_Click`

```
private void ConfigNode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var baseobj = sender as FrameworkElement;
        var myObject = baseobj.DataContext as Node;

        // find the network where the node belongs to, delete the node, update the empy_network list, update the node_dictionary
        for (int i = 0; i < network_list.Networks.Count; i++)
        {
            // network has been found
            if (network_list.Networks[i].Name == myObject.Network_name)
            {
                // find the  node

                for (int j = 0; j < network_list.Networks[i].Nodes.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (network_list.Networks[i].Nodes[j].Name == myObject.Name)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(network_list.Networks[i].Nodes[j].Name);
                        network_list.Networks[i].Nodes[j].Icon = Node.Icon_colour.yellow;
                        // update node_dictionary
                        node_dictionary[network_list.Networks[i].Nodes[j].Name].Icon = Node.Icon_colour.yellow;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The value is correctly updated, but the TreevView **does not update the image**. However, If remove the node from the tree, and then I add it back again, the image is currectly updated. 
So, can anyone please help me how to notify the TreeView that the image must be refreshed, once the `Icon` value has changed?
I read many  different posts, but I can't find the solution to this specific issue.

Comment: There is no property change notification for the DisplayedImagePath property. Make your node class implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and add a DisplayedImagePath property setter that fires the PropertyChangedEvent. If you really need to keep the property readonly, fire the PropertyChanged event at some other appropriate place in your code. As a note, the image paths should not be absolute file paths. Add the files to your visual studio project, set their Build Action to Resource, and load them by Resource File Pack URIs, like `pack://application:,,,/images/circle_green.png`.

Comment: Thank you @Clemens, your answer has put me on the right track